# What's the difference between `PCAP_IF_UP` and `PCAP_IF_RUNNING`?

Tags: pcap, libpcap

I'm looking at using pcap to get information about available network interfaces. Looking at the documentation for [`pcap_findalldevices`](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_findalldevs.3pcap.html) shows a list of flags that describe each interface. The two I'm interested in aren't adequately explained, though:

> **`PCAP_IF_UP`**: set if the device is up
>
> **`PCAP_IF_RUNNING`**: set if the device is running

**What's the difference between the two?** When would `PCAP_IF_UP` be set without `PCAP_IF_RUNNING`, or vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of those is mostly defined by the operating system.  The notion of "up" and "running" originally showed up in UN*X in the BSD networking stack; the 4.2BSD Networking Implementation Notes document says that

> The interface sets `IFF_RUNNING` after it has allocated system resources and posted an initial read on the device it manages.  This state bit is used to avoid multiple allocation requests when an interface's address is changed.

where by "the interface" they're referring to the *device driver*, not the *hardware*.  They don't say much about `IFF_UP` other than that it means that the "interface device is up", for some unspecified meaning of "up".  "Up" vs. "down" is mainly a configuration setting; an interface can be configured "up" or "down".

Most other UN*X networking stacks also have those flags.

On Windows, an attempt is made in libpcap to match that notion.

> When would `PCAP_IF_UP` be set without `PCAP_IF_RUNNING`, or vice versa?

`PCAP_IF_UP` would be set without `PCAP_IF_RUNNING` if the interface has been configured "up" but hasn't yet been fully initialized to function.  `PCAP_IF_RUNNING` won't be set if the interface isn't up.

Those flags are mainly used inside libpcap to decide which interfaces to put at the beginning of the list of interfaces - "up and running" is ahead of just "up" is ahead of "not up", because capturing on an interface that's not "running" yet may either fail because it can't be opened or won't give you any packets until it's running, and capturing on an interface that's not "up" is even more likely to fail because it can't be opened and won't give you any packets.

I'll see if the documentation can be improved.

Comment: So what if my Wi-fi card is enabled and working normally, but is not connected to a network? Would that be `IF_UP` without `IF_RUNNING`? And for an Ethernet port that's working normally but has no cable inserted, would that be the same?

Comment: "So what if my Wi-fi card is enabled and working normally, but is not connected to a network? Would that be `IF_UP` without `IF_RUNNING`?"  It would probably have both set, *but* `pcap_findalldevs()` should show `flags & PCAP_IF_CONNECTION_STATUS` as `PCAP_IF_CONNECTION_STATUS_DISCONNECTED` (or as `PCAP_IF_CONNECTION_STATUS_UNKNOWN` if it has no way, on that OS, to determine whether it's connected).

Comment: "And for an Ethernet port that's working normally but has no cable inserted, would that be the same?"  It'd be the same in that both "up" and "running" will be set, and `PCAP_IF_CONNECTION_STATUS_DISCONNECTED` might be reported.  It depends on the OS and possibly the driver.  (Perhaps there are better ways for libpcap to get physical connection information for Ethernet on some OSes.)